# How can we take advantage of version control in git while still maintaining user Privacy for our API data?

Tags: git, api

Kiva has an API available at http://build.kiva.org

We also have occasional snapshots of anonymized (to the best of our ability) data from the API. We're working now on making these snapshots update regularly, say once a week. They are big in total, 350MB compressed, > 1GB uncompressed. However, they are made up of hundreds of JSON files, and thus could benefit from git in terms of just pulling down changes.

We'd like to move our snapshots into Git and Github, to take advantage of their hosting as well as to make getting updates to the snapshots go a lot faster. Indeed, I've put up one commit of just the current snapshot here: https://github.com/coderintherye/kivaloans

However, we have a desire to not keep the git history, because we want to not make it easy to grab past history, so as to piece together data over time. The reasoning of course is that we have a legal responsibility to protect user privacy, and we have a realistic expectation that no matter how much we try to anonymize the data, if enough of it is put together, it's possible that user activity could be pinpointed to groups or individuals such as what happened with the Netflix contest: http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2010/03/netflix-cancels-contest/

Is there a way we could use Git and provide the data, while not keeping the history? One option we're considering is using git, but using rebase -i to clobber previous commits. But in order to get any benefit from Git, I think we'd at least need to keep the previous commit, and of course anyone who didn't pull regularly wouldn't get much benefit at all, because they wouldn't have the old commit to reference (or so we think?)

Or is the expectation of attempting to be good citizens with data in this way an unreasonable expectation? If so, we can abandon the idea altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the ultimate solution we decided here is perhaps unconventional, but should work for us.

We'll keep only the latest two snapshots in their json file form, and if there is a problem with the data, we will flip the repository to be private. Then, when the data is fixed and/or scrubbed to the degree needed, we'll flip it back to public.

In addition though we are probably going to provide the full snapshots via the repo download API, as suggested by AlanBarber.

Answer (score 2):

GitHub has the ability to upload static files for download outside of source control. This is often used by projects for providing pre-compiled binary installers or other large files.

You can use their [Repo Downloads](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/downloads/) API to automate this.

Comment: Nice, didn't know about Repo Downloads, that seems like the way to go if we can't figure out a way to provide the JSON files and still get rid of history/try to keep up to user expectations.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative idea: use a local git repository with full history, and employ a "build process" to publish particular snapshots up to GitHub. Example:

1. You make a series of commits and check them into your local repo
2. You decide to publish the local repo, so you start by tagging it (for good measure).
3. Your "build process" has access to a clone of the GitHub repo. In it's checkout, it deletes all the local files and preforms an export (*not* a checkout) of the local repo - specifically, of the last tagged version.
4. Exported files are committed and pushed up to GitHub.
5. GitHub repo has history, but only of snapshots.

You could employ some kind of tagging or commit message convention to make it easy to relate public commits to private commits, without exposing private history.

This "build process" would just be a script of some kind, nothing fancy.